# "if' and "else" being ignored

Tags: python

As per the title, my `if`/`else` below are not being considered — not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT epic, MAX(timestamp) FROM market_data GROUP BY epic")

epics=(
"KA.D.MXUSLN.DAILY.IP",
"CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP",
"CS.D.CRYPTOB10.TODAY.IP")

for row in cursor:
    for epic in epics:
        # If epic exists in the market_data table then take the max timestamp and request new data with date1=maxtimestamp+1min and date2=now()
        if epic in row['epic']:
            date1 = row['max'] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
            date2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        else:
            # if epic not already in market_data table then fresh new request with date1=now() and date2=now()+1min
            date1 = datetime.datetime.now()
            date2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

            # URL PRODUCTION/LIVE Enviroment - demo most likely throttled and limited
        fmt = "https://example.com/" + str(epic) + "/1/MINUTE/batch/start/{date1:%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/0/0}/end/{date2:%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/0}?format=json"
        # while date1 <= date2:
        url = fmt.format(epic, date1=date1, date2=date2)
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(url)
```

The output of cursor is:

```
CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP 2019-05-01 00:00:00
KA.D.MXUSLN.DAILY.IP 2020-02-14 14:26:00
```

The code above outputs this:

```
https://example.com/CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP/start/2019/05/01/00/01/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/10/44/0?format=json
https://example.com/CS.D.CRYPTOB10.TODAY.IP/start/2020/02/14/15/10/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/11/44/0?format=json

https://example/KA.D.MXUSLN.DAILY.IP/start/2020/02/14/14/27/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/10/44/0?format=json

https://example.com/CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP/start/2020/02/14/15/10/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/11/44/0?format=json

https://example.com/CS.D.CRYPTOB10.TODAY.IP/start/2020/02/14/15/10/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/11/44/0?format=json
```

Note - as, epics "KA.D.MXUSLN.DAILY.IP" and "CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP are already in cursor, I expect the output  to just be:

```
https://example.com/CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP/start/2019/05/01/00/01/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/10/44/0?format=json
https://example.com/CS.D.CRYPTOB10.TODAY.IP/start/2020/02/14/15/10/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/11/44/0?format=json

https://example/KA.D.MXUSLN.DAILY.IP/start/2020/02/14/14/27/0/0/end/2020/02/14/15/10/44/0?format=json
```

Why aren't my `if` and `else` being considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered, but then you continue to iterate over the other epics anyway and print those too. You could use `next` instead of your inner for loop, if you find a match, remove it from the list of epics. and then any remaining epics can be handled afterwards as required

```
for row in cursor:
    epic = next(epic for epic in epics if epic in row["epic"])

    if epic is not None:
        date1 = row['max'] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
        date2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        epics.remove(epic)
    else:
        date1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        date2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

    # URL PRODUCTION/LIVE Enviroment - demo most likely throttled and limited
    fmt = "https://example.com/" + str(epic) + "/1/MINUTE/batch/start/{date1:%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/0/0}/end/{date2:%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/0}?format=json"
    # while date1 <= date2:
    url = fmt.format(epic, date1=date1, date2=date2)
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(url)
```

Note: This leaves an issue where your `fmt` url will contain None, if there are no matches, not sure how you wish to handle this.

Comment: Thanks Sayse, I get what your saying. I have done as you suggested but now I only see epics that exist in cursor and not from my epics list.

Comment: @Aharon - I've updated my answer, you can keep track of which epics you've used. I'm not quite sure if this answers better but it looks like a closer match

Comment: I now get: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove' with what your approach

Comment: @Aharon - Ah oops, didn't notice it was a tuple, change it to a list instead

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Aharon - Use square brackets instead of brackets `[]`

Comment: Tried that still getting the error:     epics.remove[epic]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove'